# How to test and evaluate performent of a storage system? Compare between NFS and GlusterFS?

Tags: storage, nfs, glusterfs

I have an exercise at school about the title question,I have google search for couple of hours but I'm not found anythings useful.

I only know that when come to HA, GlusterFS remove the single point failure compare to NFS

Are there anythings else to compare like I/O ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of IO benchmarking tools, like iozone, bonie++ or [fio](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). The later one allows you to simulate various IO workloads - random access, streaming access mixed rw. You can easily find a tons of example in the web how to get started with fio. [For example](https://blog.ja-ke.tech/2019/08/27/nas-performance-sshfs-nfs-smb.html)